# navigation bar even spacing

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm doing some practice with layout using css, and I've come across a weird thing that I don't know how to explain. Where does the space highlighted in red in the following image come from, and how do I eliminate it?

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="menu-bar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#beachouse">Beach House</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skicabin">Ski Cabin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#countrycottage">Country Cottage</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#worldnews">World News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nationalnews">National News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#localnews">Local News</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#emailaddress">Email Address</a></li>
            <li><a href="#phonenumber">Phone Number</a></li>
            <li><a href="#postaladdress">Postal Address</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutyou">About You</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {background: #77c4d3; padding:1%; }

div.menu-bar{position: relative; max-width: 700px;}

/*Styles for both menu and submenus: */
div.menu-bar ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding:20px; background: gray;} 
div.menu-bar li { background:white; text-align:center; display:inline-block; padding:10px;}

/*Menu-specific styles: */
div.menu-bar > ul {width: 100%;}
div.menu-bar > ul > li {width:20%; border:0; margin: 0; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;}

/* Submenu-specific styles */
div.menu-bar ul ul {background-color: blue; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}

/*Hide any unodered lists that are descendents of a list element by default*/
div.menu-bar li ul { 
  display: none;
}

/*Select any unordered lists that are children of list elements that are being hovered on.*/
/* The <ul> is display:block, but the individual <li> elements are inline-block, which is what matters.*/
div.menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/33o326qb/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here to be aware of.

1.) You have space in your code, between your top-most `<li>`'s. This is a funky issue with whitespace. CSS-Tricks has [a great summary](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) of the issue. Essentially, you have to put your closing `</li>` tag back-to-back with the next opening `<li>` tag, to get rid of those tiny gaps.

2.) Secondly, your width is set to 20%. You can bump this up to even quarters, at 25%...although you'll notice that this pushes the last of your `<li>`s down a line. This is because...

3.) There is a 10px padding on `div.menu-bar li` which applies 10px of padding to the **left, right, top and bottom.** Your `div.menu-bar > ul > li` rules specify a top and bottom padding, but the left and right are left the same. My personal approach for this?

4.) Use [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). By setting this CSS property to border-box, your padding is included in the width of your elements. In other words, you can set the following CSS:

```
div.menu-bar > ul > li {
width: 25%;
margin: 0;
padding: 12px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...and you'll end up with a set of list items that have a) no funky, tiny space between them and b) are all on the same line.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow thanks! Awesome answer. I didn't know about the whitespace problem, and box-sizing makes the math a lot easier.

Comment: No problem! Yeah, the box-sizing rule is one that I put into virtually all my CSS files. Very slick. One other thing. If you *do* want space between those <li>'s, just add a percentage-based margin, and subtract that amount from the width. Ex: width:23%; margin: 0 1%; --> This will put a left & right margin of 1%, so the unit (as a whole, w/ box-sizing) is still 25%. Hope that makes sense. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

That comes from the wrapping `<ul>` below `<div class="menu-bar">`. It's width is set to `100%` in your css where you say:

```
div.menu-bar > ul {
     width: 100%;
}
```

Since the buttons don't fully take up the space in that `<ul>` there is some extra grey space. If you add a `text-align: center;` to that style, it will nicely center your buttons, as so:

```
div.menu-bar > ul {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Or check out [my JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/rspd3stu/).

Comment: That worked! I'm a little surprised, because the name of the "text-align" property makes it seem like it would only operate on text... but in this case it managed to move whole <li> elements.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange at first, but the "text-align" property applies to any tag that works "inline". So that includes buttons, <li> elements, <b> or <a> tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Each nav item's width is dependent on it's text content. It has no knowledge of how wide it's parent is. Each nav item is just shoved as far left as it can go next to it's neighbor.

If you are looking to have the nav items fill the bar evenly, you will need to use a `flex` solution. See [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a complete explanation.